# copy specific node from xml file into new one using python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I am new with python and I am trying to copy a specific part from an xml file into a new one that I create.
here is my original xml file named "doc.xml"

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!-- STATUS FM2Spirit (3.4): IP RNG1 (version 2.1): PASSED / Spec2spec OK / Spec2spirit WARNING /    4/4    (100%) / RegMatching OK / IP-XACT WARNING / RegTest OK -->
<component xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.spiritconsortium.org/XMLSchema/SPIRIT/1685-2009 http://www.spiritconsortium.org/XMLSchema/SPIRIT/1685-2009/index.xsd">
  <vendor>company</vendor>
  <library>lib</library>
  <name>name</name>
  <version>1</version>
  <memoryMaps>
    <memoryMap>
      <name>name</name>
      <description>des</description>
      <addressBlock>
        <name>name</name>
        <description>description</description>
        <baseAddress>b</baseAddress>
        <range>r</range>
        <width>w</width>
      </addressBlock>
    </memoryMap>
  </memoryMaps>
</component>
```

I want to copy only the addressBlock section and its child into a second xml that I create. the result should be

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
  <addressBlock>
    <name>name</name>
    <description>description</description>
    <baseAddress>b</baseAddress>
    <range>r</range>
    <width>w</width>
  </addressBlock>
```

here is my code so far:

```
  from lxml import etree, objectify
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
tree = etree.parse('doc.xml', parser)
root = tree.getroot()
#find tag 
src_tag = tree.find("./addressBlock")
# append the tag
root.append(src_tag)
# copy to new xml file
etree.ElementTree(root).write('output.xml', pretty_print=True, encoding='utf-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

I keep getting error in the append part and I am not sure if there is an easier way to only copy the part I need into a new xml file "output.xml" that I create, please advice

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because the `src_tag` is None

```
src_tag = tree.find("memoryMaps").find("memoryMap").find("addressBlock")
```

Hopefully helps.

Answer (score 0):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils
html = utils.getFileContent("doc.xml")
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
addressBlock = doc.addressBlock.outerHtml # Get the node string
utils.saveFile("output.xml", "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n" + addressBlock)
# Or
# doc2 = SimplifiedDoc("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>\n" + addressBlock)
# utils.saveFile("output.xml", doc2.html)
```